# Copy rows from CSV based on column value; then split into separate shuffled CSVs

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

`sh` noob so be gentle. This a preprocessing exercise using the command line, (I'm on a *mac*).

I have a large *CSV* file (*original.csv*) ~1M rows, 4 cols. I'd like to create processing script that pulls all rows based on a column value, *i.e.* get all distinct rows. There are 138393 distinct values in column 1. I'm doing the above via `awk`.

From here I want to take ~half of these found values, shuffle the rows (or randomly select) then split the two groups into two *CSV* files (*file1.csv* and *file2.csv*). FWIW it's for an machine learning exercise so splitting data into test/train.

What's an efficient way to do this? The biggest bottle necks I have now, (probably more I don't see):

1. Searching for column value match via `awk`
2. *IO* cost from copying rows to separate *csv*, then going through each *csv* + appending half values into *train.csv* and *test.csv*
3. Shuffling each file above

...BONUS: Any multithreaded solutions to speed up entire process!

My *CSV* Data is basic (and sorted by column 1 value already):

```
1,2,3.5,1112486027
1,29,3.5,1112484676
1,32,3.5,1112484819
1,47,3.5,1112484727
```

CODE:

```
#!/bin/bash


DATA_FILE=noheader.csv
awk -F "," '{ print >> ("r"$1".csv"); close("r"$1".csv") }' $DATA_FILE          # Creates seperate CSV file for each userID

ID_FILE=unique_ids.txt
if [ -e $ID_FILE ]
then
    IDX=$(wc -l unique_ids.txt | awk '{print $1}')                              # Get count of total rows in CSV 
    printf "Found %d userIDs \n" $IDX
else
   printf "File %s Not Found! \n" "$ID_FILE"
   printf "Creating Unique IDs File \n"
   cut -d , -f1 $DATA_FILE | sort | uniq > unique_ids.txt
fi

COUNT=0
START=$(date +%s)
for ((i=1; i <= $IDX; i++))                                                     # Iterate through each user CSV file 
{
    FILE=r${i}.csv

    TOT_LNO=$(wc -l $FILE  | awk -v FILE="$FILE" '{ print $1; close(FILE) }')   # Calc total number of rows in file
    SPLT_NO=$(($TOT_LNO / 2))                                                   # ~50% split of user row count for test/train split

    gshuf -n $TOT_LNO $FILE                                                     # Randomly shuffle rows in csv file

    head -n $SPLT_NO $FILE >> train_data.csv
    OFFSET=$(($SPLT_NO + 1))                                                    # Appends first line# rows of user{n} ratings to training data
    tail -n +$OFFSET $FILE >> test_data.csv                                     # Appends rows nums > line# of user{n} ratings to test data

    # awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' file2 file1                     # Prints out similarities btwn files (make sure not train/test splipapge)
    rm $FILE                                                                    # Deletes temp user rating files before proceding

    ((COUNT++))
    if ! ((COUNT % 10000))
        then
        printf "processed %d files!\n" $COUNT
    fi
}

END=$(date +%s)
TIME=$((END-START))
printf "processing runtime: %d:\n" $TIME
```

OUTPUT (assuming it was shuffled):

```
train.csv 
1,2,3.5,1112486027
1,47,3.5,1112484727

test.csv
1,32,3.5,1112484819
1,29,3.5,1112484676
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more about there being about a million rows, versus "*138393 distinct values in column 1*" .  It's unclear whether the two output files should be *500K* lines each, or about *69196* lines each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing since you didn't provide sample input and expected output that we could test against but it sounds like all you need is:

```
shuf infile.csv | awk -F, '$1==1{ print > ("outfile" (NR%2)+1 ".csv") }'
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hey Ed, my apologies - noob mistake. I edited the above a bit. Retaining the header is not necessary and I actually removed it above in the edit. I'm uncertain of where in your code you are splitting the returned values in half and outputing to 2 distinct files (train & test)? So say there are 4 rows in col[1]==1. I need 2 appended to the train.csv and 2 appended to test.csv. Are you doing this via the "(NR%2)+1" bit? I am unfamiliar with the NR param. Can you please walk me through it?

Comment: OK, I removed my code that was preserving the header. Does that script in my answer do what you wanted then?

Comment: It had to update for csv: shuf test.csv | awk -F ',' '$1==1{ print >> ("outfile" (NR%2)+1 ".csv") }'    // Right now it just grab column values = 1. How do I get it to continue through all distinct column values (there are 138933) and splitting+appending each distinct value to the 2 outfiles?

Comment: That is a very vague and ambiguous question. Just create a question with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve. See [ask] if that's not clear and in particular note the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the note Ed. Strange ppl would down vote simply for writing the final answer... 8(.  To answer your question on why the '>>'... I noticed that using '>' only captured the first occurrence of a distinct value in col[1] as opposed to finding all similar values then splitting them in half and appending to the two output files. As discussed my original CSV has >130k unique values repeated over 20 million rows in col[1]. Changing '>' to '>>' did the trick.

Comment: Oh, so you're calling the awk script from a shell loop? That's probably not necessary and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for why it should be avoided. You might want to ask a new, complete question....

Answer (score 0):

This method below is slightly faster than [the accepted `awk` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816271/6136214).

Using `shuf`, *GNU* `split`'s `-n` option, and `mv`:

```
grep '^1,' noheader.csv | shuf | split -n r/2 ; mv xaa train.csv ; mv xab test.csv
```

This won't work a *Mac*, since those use [*BSD* `split`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/split.1.html) which has no `-n` option.

Comment: This answer doesn't do what the OP asked for: `I'd like to create processing script that pulls all rows based on a column value...`. You're not testing any column value anywhere.

Comment: @EdMorton, I'm still confused about the *OP*'s usage of "*distinct*", but I'll follow your lead of column #1 = 1...